# Android アプリで折れ線グラフの任意の点から線を伸ばして複数のふきだしを表示したい

Tags: android, flutter

[WealthNavi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wealthnavi.amami) アプリのように Android で Line graph の複数のマーカーから線を引いてその先に異なるデザインのテキストを表示したいのですが、実現方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教示願いたいです 
[Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) や他のクロス プラットフォーム開発のフレームワークで実現できそうであれば Android ネイティヴから移行してもよいのではないかと考えています。
Android で Line chart を表現する手法として以下のようなライブラリがあることは分かったのですが、私にはサンプルを見つけることができませんでした。

- [List of Android Chart Libraries](https://github.com/lucasrafagnin/android-charts)
- [android-chart · GitHub Topics](https://github.com/topics/android-chart)

  - [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)
  - [line-chart](https://github.com/davidmigloz/line-chart)
  - [SciChart](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Android.Examples)
  - [AAChartCore](https://github.com/AAChartModel/AAChartCore-Kotlin)
  - [Straiberry Charts](https://github.com/STRAIBERRY-AI-INC/Straiberry-charts)

**※ 作成したい Line Chart のイメージ**
[image: 作成したい Line Chart のイメージ]

ふと閃いたのが、一つの折れ線グラフに対して一つの Tooltip を表示できるライブラリは多数存在しているので、表示したいふきだしの数だけ背景が透明な折れ線グラフを重ねればいいのではないかと  アプリがもっさりしてしまう可能性はあるかもしれませんが 
だがしかしライブラリ開発者の意図した Tooltip の使い方ではなさそうなのと、折れ線グラフ中央に文言を表示するとなると小さいサイズの端末を考慮した場合にレイアウト崩れが発生しそうで 
[Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/) で折れ線グラフを描画すれば端末サイズの配慮は不要になりそう 
但し表現できるグラフのパターンは絞られますが